# Flutter Snapshot.hasData is always returning true

Tags: android, json, api, flutter, jsonresponse

i need to fetch data from server and sometimes the data can be empty response from logcat is data `snapshot.data` is returning instance of my model `Instance of 'MyItems'` and the response from server when data is not available is

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

the problem is `snapshot.hasData` is always returning true for empty response i have tested snapshot.data == null still its true.

Model class

```
import 'dart:convert';

MyItems myItemsFromJson(String str) => MyItems.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String myItemsToJson(MyItems data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MyItems {
  MyItems({
    this.dataa,
  });

  List<Datumm> dataa;

  factory MyItems.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyItems(
    dataa: List<Datumm>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datumm.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(dataa.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datumm {
  Datumm({
    this.userId,
    this.Name,
    this.MiddelName,
  
  });

  String userId;
  String Name;
  String MiddelName;
 

  factory Datumm.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datumm(
    userId: json["user_id"],
    Name: json["Name"],
    MiddelName: json["MiddleName"],
  
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "user_id": userId,
    "Name": crbtCode,
    "MiddelName": artistName,
    
  };
}
```

My Future api call

```
 Future<MyItems> getUdata(String aName) async {
        var url =
            'https://cvbgng.com/test/${aName}';
    
        final response = await http.get(url).timeout(Duration(seconds: 15000));
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
         
          return MyItems.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        } else {
          throw Exception('Faild to load');
        }
      }
```

Comment: this is brcause `MyItems.fromJson` always returns non `null` value, anyway, whats the problem with that?

Comment: @pskink for example if no data is there how do you report there is data

Comment: `snapshot.data.dataa.isEmpty` / `snapshot.data.dataa.isNotEmpty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the condition as `snapshot.data.dataa.isEmpty` if it is true you have empty response.